# PHP: Migrating From oop without Framework into Zend php frameword

Tags: php, mysql, oop, forms, frameworks

I have completed my website couple months ago, in php 5 (full oop), and now I'm think of migrating into PHP framework (Zend looks fine).

My question is, how hard is it to migrate from oop to any php framework?
What is the easiest Framework i can migrate to?

**Noting that Functionality of my website depends on:**

1. A lot of MySQL Searching and Updating.
2. There is a lot of forms in the web, some of them can reach more than 50+ fields.
3. A lot of classes that handle logic of website specially analyze submitted forms with data on database.

I have no experience with php frameworks, so can you please tell me which framework would be least painful to move all my classes there and get them running fast?

Comment: Zend framework as a first framework isn't easy. It's one of those frameworks that assumes you know what you are doing, having said that though, there are plenty of tutorials - you just need time to go through them.

Comment: I agree with Jason, IF you want to learn something a bit easier and more lightweight, take a look at Yii, or EZComponents.

Comment: Something easier would be a more light weight framework like kohana or code igniter, one that allows you to work with your current oop structure, assuming it is MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How hard is to migrate... is a good questions...

A little example:
You can write your own queries... You can write queries in a "ZF-like" style...

then if your OOP Classes are well formed (I mean well formed for use them into the ZF enviroment) your migration will be quick and easy...

but you also have to understand ZF Mechanics

Keep a look to those beast:
 - Zend Forms
 - Zend Decorators

IMHO the two beast of ZF

Comment: Agreed, Zend Forms / Zend Decorators are a real struggle :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is like

> How long is a piece of a string?

We don't know your application, the information you gave us is too vague and we don't know your experience in php at all. Porting code from one architecture to another can be easy (if the basic styles and techniques are the same) or pretty impossible (if you wrote a spaghetti application).

Also the question for the best framework to port to is impossible to answer, as long as we don't know your application.

The main question is: Do your application make use of design patterns (and do you understand them **fully**),or is "OOP" just the use of classes instead of functions, for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to ZendFrame work you need to convert

your  **sql queries** using [Zend Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html)

You need to convert your forms into [Zend Forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html).

Zend provides classes for form validation. So you need use [Zend Validation Classes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html)  for the form validation.